# SqlDataSource Populate dropdownlist with or without parameter

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I use SqlDataSource control to list out search result when user choose a date, but if the date is null, then it will list out all record. How to do the sql command?

```
SELECT Ref_No as name, Job_Order_ID as value 
FROM Job_Order 
WHERE (Status <> 'JO_Completed') AND (Delivery_Date = @jaDate) 
OR (Status <> 'JO_Completed') ORDER BY Ref_No
```

code to generate dropdownlist

```
 <asp:SqlDataSource ID="NewJobOrderDS" runat="server" SelectCommand="SELECT Ref_No as name, Job_Order_ID as value FROM Job_Order WHERE (Status <> 'JO_Completed') AND (Delivery_Date = @jaDate) ORDER BY Ref_No" OnSelecting="NewJobOrderDS_Selecting">
                                  <SelectParameters>
                                        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="txtJADate2" Name="jaDate" PropertyName="Text" Type="DateTime"/>   
                                   </SelectParameters>
                                </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: are you sure about your query? Prop1 AND Prop2 OR Prop1 = Prop1 always.. no matter what is the truth value of Prop2... all i am trying to say is that your where clause is equivalent with (Status <> 'JO_Completed')

Comment: @avi I dunno how to do the query.. The condition is if jaDate = null then i will do select statement WHERE (Status <> 'JO_Completed')  else if jaDate have value then select statement WHERE (Status <> 'JO_Completed') AND (Delivery_Date = jaDate)

Comment: You said: "if the date is null ", does this means your dropdown also has null values? Can you show the same. Also show how data is binded to dropdown

Comment: @FlopScientist Yes. If the date is null,the dropdown also will have the null values. I had edit my post for the code to bind dropdown.

Comment: I had solve it by having 2 sqldatasourceID and code for it is protected void txtJADate2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {  ddlNewJobOrder.DataSourceID = null;
        if (txtJADate2.Text =="")
        {          
            ddlNewJobOrder.DataSource = NewJobOrderDS1;
        }
        else
        {
            ddlNewJobOrder.DataSource = NewJobOrderDS2;
        }
        ddlNewJobOrder.DataBind();
    }